# Need help using connect module in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I am new to node. I am trying to use the connect function to use socket.io. For some reason every time I try to use it I get the following error message.

I can't seem to find out what I am doing wrong. Any help would be really appreciated!

```
var app = connect().use(connect.static('public')).listen(3000);
                                      ^

TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/eldanshkolnikov/Dropbox/Node/server.js:19:39)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Comment: Did you remember to `var connect = require('connect');`?

Comment: Recent versions of Connect [no longer have middleware bundled](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware), including `connect.static()`. The docs recommend using [`serve-static`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static), which will need to be installed and required separately -- `connect().use(require('serve-static')('public')).listen(3000)`.